# Iterate over a state variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, iterator

I'm iterating over a state that is formatted like this:

```
this.state = {
    dayTime: {
        Monday:['7:00', '8:00'], Tuesday: ['9:00', '12:00']
    }
 }
```

When I try to iterate over the dayTime state I can't (tried `for()`, `.foreach` and `.map`).

I can access `this.state.dayTime.Monday` but I was wondering if there is a recommended way of doing iterations like this.

I've attached some of my attempts below:

```
this.state.dayTimeArray.forEach((ele)=>{
    console.log(ele)//error
}, this)

this.state.dayTimeArray.map(function(ele){
    console.log(ele)//error
}, this)
```

Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot iterate through object the same way as you would do in arrays. 
You have few options here:

With Object.entries to get an array of entries: [key, value]

```
Object.entries(this.state.dayTimeArray).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value);
})
```

With Object.keys() to only get the keys [monday, tuesday]

```
Object.keys(this.state.dayTimeArray).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(key, this.state.dayTimeArray[key]);
})
```

Use Object.values() to only get the values ['7:00', '8:00'], ['9:00', '12:00']

```
Object.values(this.state.dayTimeArray).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(value);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate over the object properties, you can use any one of [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) or [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (whichever suits your needs best) to get an array of properties which you can iterate on

With `Object.entries`

```
Object.entries(this.state.dayTimeArray).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value);
})
```

With `Object.keys()`

```
Object.keys(this.state.dayTimeArray).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(key, this.state.dayTimeArray[key]);
})
```

Use `Object.values()` to get only the values

```
Object.values(this.state.dayTimeArray).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(value);
})
```